# Elegant way to return the longer of two strings

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that returns the longer of two strings. So far this is what I have:

```
maxString :: String -> String -> String
maxString a b
    | (length a) > (length b) = a
    | otherwise = b
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to write this. Note: the two arguments cannot be in a list. They must be separate arguments to allow for currying.

Thoughts?

Comment: beware of the infinite lists!

Answer (score 9):

So far all answers except Tejing's fully traverse both arguments. This one only traverses as far as the end of the shorter one.

```
longest a b = l' a b where
  l' _ [] = a
  l' [] _ = b
  l' (_:ar) (_:br) = l' ar br
```

Comment: This is interesting . kudos

Answer (score 8):

You can use existing Haskell facilities in `Data.Ord` and `Data.Function` and obtain a one-liner as follows:

```
maxString' x y = maximumBy (compare `on` length) [x, y]
```

Code:

```
import Data.Ord
import Data.Function
import Data.List

maxString' x y = maximumBy (compare `on` length) [x, y]

*Main> maxString' "ab" "c"
"ab"
```

-- EDIT --

As @DavidYoung pointed out,

```
compare `on` length
```

above can also be written in a shorter form:  `comparing length`

Comment: You can also write ``compare `on` length`` as `comparing length`.

Answer (score 8):

Played around with this one a bit. I wanted it to be a one-liner as well as having complexity `O(min(n,m))`. (ie. working even with infinite lists)

```
maxList :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
maxList s s' = if s == zipWith const s s' then s' else s
```

Answer (score 6):

That's pretty much the most concise way to write it. However, the version below will terminate even when one list is infinite (O(min(a,b)) instead of O(a + b)).

```
compareLengths :: [a] -> [b] -> Ordering
compareLengths [    ] [    ] = EQ
compareLengths (a:as) [    ] = GT
compareLengths [    ] (b:bs) = LT
compareLengths (a:as) (b:bs) = compareLengths as bs

maxList :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
maxList a b = case compareLengths a b of
  GT -> a
  _  -> b
```

Also, there's no real reason to limit your function to just Strings when it would make sense for arbitrary lists.